# How can I preview a excel file from server in webpage?

Tags: html, portlet, aspose-cells

I'm writing a website that allow user upload excel file, if it pass the validation, user can convert the content into database, otherwise the website will tell user where is the problem, which cells of excel file is wrong.

So I'd like to make the webpage is available to display/preview the excel file after user upload it.

In my website, after user upload the file, back-end will do the validation, and generate a new excel file out (using aspose-cell), if there are any mistake, the back-end will change the font or cells color of the mistake parts.

So I suppose the website will open the new excel file, and allow user to see the real-content of the excel file, including the font & cells color.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can work with Aspose.Cells for GridWeb to work with Worksheets. You may please visit following link for more details. Let us know if you face any problem.

https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Aspose.Cells.GridWeb

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.